# Android ViewPager: Scroll to next item only when the previous item is scrolled to 90%

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a view pager implementation in my app. I want to change its scroll behaviour.

Currently (by default) when we scroll to 50% (almost) of the current item, the view pager scrolls to the next item. I want to change this behaviour. I want that instead of 50%, the next item should come up when the current item is scrolled to 90%. Is it possible to implement this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of :

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener
```

the solution could be using SimpleOnPageChangeListener method and override it's onPageScrolled method:

```
     mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
            if (positionOffset> 0.9f){
                scrolPage()
            }
        }
    }) ;
```

please take a look into the positionOffset documentation:

```
* @param positionOffset Value from [0, 1) indicating the offset from the page at position.
```